# Android application keeps crashing on Chrome OS

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-arc

I am trying to run my Android application on Chrome OS via ARC Welder. However my application keeps crashing.
Error message that I see in console (chrome://inspect#apps) of my application does not provide much useful information. Error message says:

```
    plugin.js:1387 Audio stream failed to open NavigatorUserMediaError {}constraintName: ""message: ""name: "InvalidStateError"__proto__: 

NavigatorUserMediaError(anonymous function) @ plugin.js:1387
    gen_index.min.html:1 NativeClient: NaCl module crashed
```

I tried to Google about this but could not find any useful information.
Please let me know how to proceed on this if you know the solution.
Below are the details of my Chrome

```
Version 45.0.2431.0 dev
Platform 7173.2.0 (Official Build) dev-channel peach_pi-freon
Firmware Google_Peach_Pi.4482.94.0
```

It's a Samsung ChromeBook with processor "SAMSUNG EXYNOS5"

Additional Info: This same application works fine in Chrome browser on my Windows 7 Machine.

Comment: Thanks for filing the bug in the chromium issue tracker, that's probably the better venue for this type of problem since there is no programming help to offer.